# Grails console - Unable to find class?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm working through the "Grails in Action" book, and I'm stuck at that part that introduces the grails console. From my project directory, I typed "grails console" to open a console window, and the console even output information indicating it was compiling classes, but when I type this into the console:

`new Quote(author:'Larry Wall',content:'There is more than one method to our madness.').save()`

I get this error:

```
unable to resolve class Quote 
 at line: 1, column: 1
```

The Quote class exists in Quote.groovy in `grails-app/domain/qotd/Quote.groovy`, and I'm not able to run the above command.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Did you try importing the package that contains your domain class before trying to instantiate it?

```
import qotd.Quote
new Quote(author:'Larry Wall',content:'There is more than one method to our madness.').save()
```

to be sure you can also try specifying the full qualified name:

```
new qotd.Quote(author:'Larry Wall',content:'There is more than one method to our madness.').save()
```

Comment: Odd. Since the book didn't mention it, I assumed I was getting auto-import magic, or something.

Comment: This is a problem with Grails In Action. At the time of writing this worked, but it changed with later grails versions ...

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, and despite doing what this answer suggests, I am still not successful. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I'm going through the MEAP of Grails in Action second edition (2.1.1) and found that the solution is run:

```
grails clean
grails console
```

type the code in the groovy console again and run

Answer (score 0):

Looks like selecting "Refresh Dependencies" from the Grails Tools context menu also fixes problems like this.